# Card management with Google fit on Android

Tags: google-play-store, google-fit

Google Fit is an Android app. When you run it, on the first screen they have cards with weight graph and personal records. These cards may be deleted  by dragging them side ways. That is how i deleted them. How can I bring them back? I looked through settings menu but card management is not there.

Please help.

One of the cards namely "Your weight" is returned the next day I deleted it.

So far I rated the app as "one star" in Android-Store to send a message to developers that the card management is not that easy to find. If they reply to my review, I'll post it here.

Thanks.

Comment: I think Google have bigger fish to fry than your 1* review of their app.

Answer (score 0):

Those option are for starter user i.e to show the new user option available on dashboard. Where ass these options are available in app already . Lets see below .

The first option is **Create a new Goal** :- If you dismiss the card then there is option on Home to add a goal .

And the second option is **Easy tracking** :- This is just for description to let the user know the features of app and what activities user can track with `GoogleFit`.

`GoogleFit` App also shows some random cards to entertain and let their user know the features of app and track of their Activities time to time. Once to swipe random card you will get one time option to `undo` the action if you skip it then card is gone forever.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, please do it more concise. Please remove irrelevant images and wordings. Thank you.

Comment: Another thing. One of the cards namely "Your weight" is returned the next day I deleted it. It is not gone forever.